# Neo4j: How to merge existing data (in a database) and non existing data (in CSV)

Tags: database, csv, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I already have nodes as "projects" in my database. Also I have tags in a CSV.
The CSV looks like this:

```
|name|
|Information1|
|Information2|
|...|
```

I'd like to put them both together, so that one specific project will have all information in the CSV with the relationship "belongs_to".
The result should looks like this:

```
Information1 - belongs_to -> Project1
Information2 - belongs_to -> Project1
```

How can I do this? I tried different things, but nothing was right.

I thought I could load the CSV first and secondly get the relationship like:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:/.../projects.csv" AS row
CREATE (:AddInformation {name: row.name});
...

MATCH (p:PROJECT { id:1 }) 
WITH range(1,4) AS RANGE, p 
FOREACH (r IN RANGE | 
    MERGE (add:AddInformation { id:r })-[rel:belongs_to]->(p))
```

This works, but in this case there were just new AddInformation, not the one I was looking for.

So again my question: How can I put one project together (with a relationship) with information from a specific CSV?
(Would it help to identify the AddInformation by ID in the CSV or add the information, that they should match with a specific project?)

Best regards, Finfan

Answer (score 0):

FOREACH isn't the right one for that.
Now I used a second property for my AddInformation.

The CSV is now looking like this:

```
|name        |property|
|Information1|...     |
|Information2|...     |
|...         |...     |
```

So firstly I load this CSV, secondly I use this command:

```
MATCH (p:Project), (add:AddInformation) WHERE id(p)=8 AND HAS (add.property)
    MERGE (add)-[:belongs_to]->(p)
```

Afterwards I delete this property and everything is fine.

```
MATCH (m {property:"Insert"}) REMOVE m.property RETURN m
```